# Why is an empty \line added when \insert is used?

Tags: floats, page-breaking, tex-core, plain-tex

Consider the following example:

```
\tracingonline=1
\tracingoutput=1
\gdef\makefootline{} \gdef\makeheadline{}
\insert\topins{\vbox to\vsize{\hrule height \vsize width 300pt}}
\end
```

The log file contains this:

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
...\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0


Completed box being shipped out [2]
\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 633.20255fill
..\glue(\topskip) 10.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
```

It is not clear where the elements on page 2 come from (`\topskip`, `\line{}` and `\vfill`). This behavior is not documented in chapter 15 of *The TeXbook*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to explain this using quotes from the TeXbook.

## Summary

When the main vertical list isn't empty at the point where the `\end` token is digested, TeX [inserts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499073/73317) the equivalent of `\line{}\vfill\penalty-'10000000000` into the main vertical list, exercises the page builder and prepares to read `\end` again (TeXbook pp. 264 and 283). In your example, this `\line{}` brings the first box to the main vertical list, because the insertion item is not a box item. As a consequence, TeX prepends `\topskip` glue to this box, which is `10pt` here. This `\topskip` glue is a valid breakpoint because it is immediately preceded by the insertion item; the associated cost is zero. The next legal breakpoint is the `\vfill` glue following the `\hbox` that corresponds to the aforementioned `\line{}`. The cost associated with this `\vfill` glue is infinite because the associated penalty is zero and the page would be overfull should a break occur at the `\vfill` item (i.e., *b* = ∞; this is because the insertion plus the `\topskip` glue plus the empty `\hbox` are 10 points too high in total to fit on the page). Therefore TeX breaks a new page at the best breakpoint seen so far, which is the `\topskip` glue. Thus, page 1 only contains material from the insertion (the `\output` routine wraps this material inside two `\vbox`es). Page 2 contains a new `\topskip` glue item, the empty `\hbox` and the `\vfill` glue item.

## Analysis

As said above, if the main vertical list isn't empty at the point where the `\end` token is digested, TeX inserts the equivalent of `\line{}\vfill\penalty-'10000000000` into the main vertical list, exercises the page builder and prepares to read `\end` again. In your example, this brings 10 points of `\topskip` glue followed by an empty `\hbox to \hsize` onto the current page (among others). In this particular case, the `\topskip` glue item is a valid breakpoint<sup>1</sup> and TeX immediately computes the associated cost (remember that it is exercising the page builder as part of the special `\end` processing); it finds that this cost is zero, because the insertion is exactly `\vsize` high. Thus, the conditions for starting a new page are not fulfilled yet (TeXbook p. 112, § 2).

Therefore, TeX continues with the implicitly-added items. After the empty `\hbox` comes the `\vfill` glue: it moves these two items from “recent contributions” to the “current page” list. The `\hbox` is not a legal breakpoint, but the `\vfill` item is, since it is immediately preceded by a non-discardable item (the `\hbox`). TeX computes the cost *c* associated with this second legal breakpoint and finds *c* = ∞, because there is `10pt` material in excess on the current page, up to and excluding the breakpoint (the page goal was decreased by `\vsize` and became `0pt` when the insertion item was moved to the “current page,” and the page total went from `0pt` to `10pt` with the `\topskip` glue and remained unchanged after the empty `\hbox`). According to the rules given on p. 112 of the TeXbook, this causes TeX to decide that it is time to break a new page at the best remembered breakpoint, which is the one at the `\topskip` glue (associated cost: 0).

This glue item from `\topskip`, the empty `\hbox` and the `\vfill` glue item are thus all put back at the top of the “recent contributions” list, followed by the `\penalty-'10000000000` item that has been waiting there all the time since `\end` inserted it (cf. long paragraph p. 125). Since `\holdinginserts` is `0` by default, the insertion item is then removed from the “current page,” its contents is appended to `\box\topins` with no interline glue, the items remaining on the “current page” (none here!) are put together in `\box255`, and finally the `\output` routine is invoked and ships out page 1.

Then TeX starts page 2. The first thing it does is to exercise the page builder, since an `\output` routine has just ended (cf. p. 122, § 2, item (e), reproduced in footnote 3). So, TeX tries to move items from “recent contributions” to the “current page.” The glue item from `\topskip` that was put back at the top of the “recent contributions” is discarded at this occasion (there is no box yet on the “current page”) and immediately replaced by a new `\topskip` glue item,<sup>2</sup> since the `\hbox` item that follows it will be the first box on the current page. TeX moves this box to the current page, followed by the `\vfill` glue item and the `\penalty-'10000000000`. The `\vfill` glue is a legal breakpoint, but it doesn't fulfill the conditions given p. 112 for finishing the page (the associated values are `p=0` and `c=100000`). The penalty item that follows, on the other hand, does fulfill them (p ≤ −10000).

All remaining items except the breakpoint, namely the `\penalty-'10000000000`, thus went on page 2. This penalty item is changed into a `\penalty10000` and put back at the top of the “recent contributions” (TeXbook p. 125), but immediately discarded as the page builder is exercised (again due to § 2 of p. 122, item (e), as reproduced in footnote 3). Because of this, the main vertical list is finally empty and since the `\output` routine executed `\shipout` for page 2, `\deadcycles` is `0` when TeX sees `\end` for the second time. According to the TeXbook p. 283, this terminates the job.

## Confirmation of the analysis with experiments

TeXbook p. 264:

> When TeX sees an `\end` command, it terminates the job only if the main vertical list has been entirely output and if `\deadcycles=0`. Otherwise it inserts the equivalent of
>
> ```latex
> \line{} \vfill \penalty-'10000000000
> ```
>
> into the main vertical list, and prepares to read the `\end` token again.

Notes:

- This corresponds to the code [posted by David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499073/73317).
- On page 283, Knuth adds the precision that the page builder is exercised after the aforementioned box/glue/penalty combination has been added to the main vertical list.

We can show that in your example, TeX sees the `\end` token before the main vertical list has been emptied. In order to do this, insert `\showlists` before `\end` in your example and you'll see:

```latex
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\insert253, natural size 643.20255; split(10.0,16383.99998); float cost 0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
total height 0.0
 goal height 0.0
\insert253 adds 643.20255
prevdepth ignored

./insert.tex:5: OK.
l.5 \showlists
```

In contrast, if you insert `\null\break\showlists` before `\end`, you'll see:

```latex
### vertical mode entered at line 0
prevdepth 0.0

./insert.tex:5: OK.
l.5 \null\break\showlists
```

*That* is an empty vertical list (displayed after page 1 and an underfull page 2 have been shipped out). So, getting back to your example: when TeX sees `\end`, it doesn't consider yet that the page is full (it would indeed be possible to “rewind” using a box followed by negative kerns or skips), so it doesn't call the `\output` routine yet. We can insert some more diagnostic tools to confirm the precisions I added here:

```latex
\tracingonline=1
\tracingoutput=1
\tracingmacros=2
\tracingpages=1
\gdef\makefootline{} \gdef\makeheadline{}
\insert\topins{\vbox to\vsize{\hrule height \vsize width 300pt}}
\showlists
\end
```

which prints:

```latex
%% goal height=643.20255, max depth=4.0

### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\insert253, natural size 643.20255; split(10.0,16383.99998); float cost 0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
total height 0.0
 goal height 0.0
\insert253 adds 643.20255
prevdepth ignored

./insert.tex:7: OK.
l.7 \showlists

% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#
% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*
\output->{\plainoutput }

\plainoutput ->\shipout \vbox {\makeheadline \pagebody \makefootline }\advancepageno \ifnum \outputpenalty >-\@MM \else \dosupereject \fi 

(...)

Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
...\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0


\advancepageno ->\ifnum \pageno <\z@ \global \advance \pageno \m@ne \else \global \advance \pageno \@ne \fi 
%% goal height=643.20255, max depth=4.0
% t=10.0 g=643.20255 b=10000 p=0 c=100000#
% t=10.0 plus 1.0fill g=643.20255 b=0 p=-1073741824 c=-1073741824#
\output->{\plainoutput }

\plainoutput ->\shipout \vbox {\makeheadline \pagebody \makefootline }\advancepageno \ifnum \outputpenalty >-\@MM \else \dosupereject \fi 

(...)

Completed box being shipped out [2]
\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 633.20255fill
..\glue(\topskip) 10.0
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x469.75499
..\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
```

The `%% goal height=643.20255, max depth=4.0` line is printed when

> the first box or insertion enters the current page list

(TeXbook p. 113). This is your `\insert`, okay. Right after that, `\showlists` indeed shows this insert on the current page:

```latex
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\insert253, natural size 643.20255; split(10.0,16383.99998); float cost 0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0

(...)
```

This is because, according to the TeXbook p. 281:

> TeX also exercises the page builder (see below), after an `\insert` has been appended in vertical mode.

So, *the page builder has been exercised* before TeX even read `\showlists`. The `\insert` has been moved right away from the “recent contributions” to the “current page.” But TeX doesn't consider yet that the page has to be finished, it *won't invoke the `\output` routine yet!* Indeed, remember what comes next in the log:

```latex
% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#
% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*
\output->{\plainoutput }
```

The first line with `g=0` clearly shows that the `\insert` has been put on the current page, otherwise the page goal would still be `643.20255` points. Now, remember what is said in the TeXbook p. 114:

> TeX inserts special glue just before the first box on each page. This special glue is equal to `\topskip`, except that the natural space has been decreased by the height of the first box, or it has been set to zero in lieu of a negative value.

The `% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#` line corresponds to the `\topskip` glue automatically inserted before the box equivalent to `\line{}`. It is a legal breakpoint because of the quote from footnote 1 below, and was printed when the page builder was exercised as part of the special processing of `\end` (otherwise, it would have been printed after the `\hbox` command had been digested by TeX, according to the TeXbook p. 282). However, the conjunction of `p=0` and `c=0` at the end of that line implies that TeX sees *no reason to break a new page* at the best breakpoint seen so far (marked with `#`: first legal breakpoint here). Indeed, remember paragraph 2 of page 112:

> If the resulting *c* is less than or equal to the smallest cost seen so far on the current page, TeX remembers the current breakpoint as the best so far. And if *c* = ∞ or if *p* ≤ −10000, TeX seizes the initiative and breaks the page at the best remembered breakpoint.

(the last “if” is most probably an “if and only if”). The `\topskip` breakpoint being a glue item, its associated *p* value is 0; since the insertion is exactly `\vsize` high, breaking at this `\topskip` item would cause a page badness equal to zero (`b=0`), therefore the cost *c* associated with the first breakpoint is indeed `c=0` according to the *b* + *p* + *q* expression from page 111 (`\insertpenalties` is zero after the `\insert`).

So, after putting the `\topskip` glue on the “current page” due to the special `\end` processing and computing the cost associated with this potential breakpoint, TeX is still waiting for more material before deciding that a page break has to happen. So, it takes the next items inserted in “recent contributions” by `\end`, and moves them one by one to the “current page”. The `\hbox` isn't a breakpoint, it is simply moved; the `\vfill` is also moved—there is no reason to discard it—and *is* a legal breakpoint, since it is preceded by a non-discardable item (the `\hbox`). The page builder computes its associated cost:

```latex
% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*
```

This line being printed for a glue item, the associated *p* value is `0`, thus p < 10000. Because of the `\topskip` glue item (10 points) and the empty `\hbox`, breaking at the `\vfill` glue item would cause an overfull page, hence `b=*` and the computed cost `c=*`. This decides TeX to break the page at the best remembered breakpoint (the `\topskip`) and finally invoke the `\output` routine for page 1:

```latex
\output->{\plainoutput }

\plainoutput ->\shipout \vbox {\makeheadline \pagebody \makefootline }\advancepageno \ifnum \outputpenalty >-\@MM \else \dosupereject \fi 

(...)
```

So, you get a second page containing the (new) `\topskip` glue item, an empty `\hbox` equivalent to `\line{}` and another glue item from `\vfill` (all wrapped in two `\vbox`es: one from `\plainoutput` and one from `\pagebody`).

You would like to do something to `\shipout` page 1 after the insertion, but before `\end` added the equivalent of `\line{} \vfill \penalty-'10000000000`, right? First idea: append a penalty after the `\insert` that forces page breaking, e.g., with `\break` (which is equivalent to `\penalty -10000`). Alas, this doesn't work because:

1. A `\penalty` seen in vertical mode causes TeX to exercise the page builder (TeXbook p. 280), and therefore to try to move things from the “recent contributions” to the “current page”.
2. This sentence from p. 112 of the TeXbook:

   > Whenever TeX is moving an item from the top of the “recent contributions” to the bottom of the “current page,” it discards a discardable item (glue, kern, or penalty) if the current page does not contain any boxes.

   which is the case here (the insertion item on the “current page” isn't a box item).

Indeed, if we try:

```latex
\tracingonline=1
\gdef\makefootline{} \gdef\makeheadline{}
\insert\topins{\vbox to\vsize{\hrule height \vsize width 300pt}}
\break
\showlists
\end
```

we get to see:

```latex
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\insert253, natural size 643.20255; split(10.0,16383.99998); float cost 0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
total height 0.0
 goal height 0.0
\insert253 adds 643.20255
prevdepth ignored

./insert.tex:5: OK.
l.5 \showlists
```

As before, the “current page” has the insertion at the point where `\showlists` is executed, but the penalty has been discarded, as could be guessed from the previous quote. Compare this with:

```latex
\tracingonline=1
\tracingpages=1
\gdef\makefootline{} \gdef\makeheadline{}
\insert\topins{\vbox to\vsize{\hrule height \vsize width 300pt}}
\topskip=0pt\null\penalty100
\showlists
\end
```

which gives:

```latex
%% goal height=643.20255, max depth=4.0
% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#
% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=100 c=100

### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\insert253, natural size 643.20255; split(10.0,16383.99998); float cost 0
.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
..\rule(643.20255+0.0)x300.0
\glue(\topskip) 0.0
\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
\penalty 100
total height 0.0
 goal height 0.0
\insert253 adds 643.20255
prevdepth 0.0
```

Because of the `\null` (an empty `\hbox`), the penalty wasn't discarded this time; it got onto the current page and was noted as being a legal breakpoint (`t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=100 c=100`), though not the best seen so far (that one has the trailing `#`). And thanks to the `\topskip=0pt`, we got all this on page 1 (with a positive `\topskip`, we would have had c = ∞ for the `\penalty100` breakpoint, thus again a page break at the `\topskip` glue, then a second page). With `\topskip=0pt`, the insertion, the `\topskip` glue and the `\null` box all fit on the first page. Therefore, all we need to do in order to get only one page of output as you probably wanted, is to trigger a page break after the `\null` box. We can do this using a penalty, which won't be discarded this time since *there is already a box* on the “current page list.” Here we go:

```latex
\tracingonline=1
\tracingpages=1
\gdef\makefootline{} \gdef\makeheadline{}
\insert\topins{\vbox to\vsize{\hrule height \vsize width 300pt}}
\topskip=0pt\null\break
\end
```

which gives the following output:

```latex
%% goal height=643.20255, max depth=4.0
% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#
% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=-10000 c=-10000#
[1] )
Output written on insert.pdf (1 page, 968 bytes).
Transcript written on insert.log.

TeX Output finished at Mon Jul  8 10:11:58
```

One page of output, broken at the `\penalty -10000` from our `\break`.

---

**Footnotes**

1. We are precisely in the case described page 114 of the TeXbook:

   > If insertions occur before the first box, the `\topskip` glue before that box is considered to be a valid breakpoint; this is the only case in which a completed page might not contain a box.
2. This can be verified with code such as `\output=\expandafter{\the\output\global\topskip=6pt}` inserted before `\end` and watching the TeX messages printed with `\tracingonline=1\tracingpages=1\tracingoutput=1\relax` (idea from Igor).
3. Paragraph 2 of the TeXbook p. 122 gives the conditions in which the page builder is exercised:

   > TeX is liable to invoke an output routine whenever it tries to move something from the list of recent contributions to the current page, because it might discover a page break with *c* = ∞ then. Here is a list of the times when that can happen: (a) At the beginning or end of a paragraph, provided that this paragraph is being contributed to the main vertical list. (b) At the beginning or end of a displayed equation within such a paragraph. (c) After completing an `\halign` in vertical mode. (d) After contributing a box or penalty or insertion to the main vertical list. (e) After an `\output` routine has ended.

Comment: There is an error in your answer: "It is this precise \topskip that decides TeX to finally call the \output routine for page 1: % t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=* ...". In fact, `\topskip` decides  here: `% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#`. `% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*` is decided by `\vfill`. See p.113.

Comment: I stand by my assertion: the `\topskip` causes 10 points “two much material” on the page (`t=10.0 g=0.0`); this explains the `c=*` which causes TeX to say “Oh, it's time to break a new page, let's find the best breakpoint we've seen so far and rewind.” The `#` marks the best breakpoint seen so far, and it is the `\topskip` as show by the `t=0.0` on the line ending with `#`. AFAICT, the `\vfill` is not seen at all while processing page 1 of the original example.

Comment: Please read this sentence on p.113: "However, the % lines are generated by the penalty or glue items that follow the hboxes, not by the boxes themselves." This means that the first `%` can be caused only by glue (and this is confirmed by the fact that `\showlists` is between `%%` and `%`). And the glue is, of course, `\topskip`. **It** causes the first `%` line. Then comes empty hbox, which stands 10pt lower. Next `%` can be caused also only by glue. And that glue is `\vfill`.

Comment: (was too long to add to the previous comment) The breakpoint itself doesn't stay on the page that is about to be finished: TeX always breaks “right before the chosen breakpoint”; that is why the line ending with `#` has `t=0.0` instead of `t=10.0`.

Comment: BTW, it's possible to see that old `\topskip` is indeed discarded and new `\topskip` is used by adding this before `\end`: `\topskip=5pt\output=\expandafter{\the\output\global\topskip=6pt}`

Comment: I agree that the second line (`t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*`) must be triggered by the `\vfill` (second legal breakpoint), so I withdraw this sentence from my earlier comment: “AFAICT, the `\vfill` is not seen at all while processing page 1 of the original example.” Still, it is the `\topskip` that triggers too much material on the page and hence the second page, which I believe is what I said in the answer. If this is badly said, I'll fix it. “right before the chosen breakpoint” is not a phrase coming straight from the book, it translates what I remember concerning breakpoints.

Comment: These two sentences from p. 125 say essentially the same (with more precision): When the best page break is finally chosen, TeX removes everything after the chosen breakpoint from the bottom of the “current page,” and puts it all back at the top of the “recent contributions.” The chosen breakpoint itself is placed at the very top of the recent contributions.

Comment: I'll test your `\topskip` experiment in `\output`, but will be mostly away for a little while.

Comment: No, it's `\vfill` that triggers too much material. Because line corresponding to the trigger (second `%`-line) is caused by `\vfill`. But the break itself happens at `\topskip` (previous `%`-line).

Comment: Hmm, this is what I was trying to say. Maybe badly. Let's rephrase: the *decision* that there will be a second page is taken when TeX sees the `\vfill` (thanks for pointing this out), but the 10 points in excess (without which there would be no second page in this example) do come from the `\topskip` inserted before the hbox for `\line{}`. It is important indeed to note that the decision is taken when `\vfill` is seen, because this makes it possible to “rewind” in order to break somewhere *after* the `\topskip` (even after the `\line{}`), for instance by inserting `\line{}\kern-10pt\break`...

Comment: ... before the `\end` token (this makes the `\line{}` explicit rather than implicitly added by TeX, but the behavior is the same). This way, we can get the `\topskip` glue, the following `\line` and the negative `\kern` on page 1. Note that this doesn't work if you try to replace my `\kern-10pt` with `\vskip-10pt`, because that `\vskip` would be a legal breakpoint with infinity cost at `t=10.0`, and thus in this case, the page break would happen at the `\topskip` preceding the `\line{}`, as in the example.

Comment: I could reproduce your test with `\output=\expandafter{\the\output\global\topskip=6pt}`, thanks for providing it. I had tried something similar when writing the summary of my answer, but I think I had forgotten the `\global`, hence I didn't manage to prove by experience that indeed a new `\topskip` was inserted on page 2 after the `\topskip` breakpoint of page 1 was discarded when TeX tried to move it from “recent contributions” to the “current page list“ for the second page.

Comment: In fact, it is not even the `\vfill` that causes TeX to take the decision, it is the following `\penalty`, because the `\vfill` doesn't exercise the page builder (see p. 281 and use `\tracingcommands=1`). I'll update the above comments.

Comment: I don't see from the trace that `\penalty-'10000000` exercises the page builder, from p.281 either. One more question: Do you know why there is `\penalty 10000` in "recent contributions" after second page was output? ("recent contributions" list may be seen by adding `\output=\expandafter{\the\output\showlists}`)

Comment: Gasp, I had edited the comments in my Emacs... Concerning the `\penalty-'10000000`, you only see it in the output of `\tracingcommands=1` when you explicitly put yourself `\line{}\vfill\penalty-'10000000000` before `\end`. The implicitly inserted stuff doesn't show up. I discovered that the penaly (not the `\vfill`) was triggering the decision because I noticed that in my previous experiment, `\vskip-10pt` was not enough to trigger a new `% ` line, even though it's a valid breakpoint when following the box. With `\tracingcommands=1`, I saw the `% ` line comes only after `{\penalty}`...

Comment: ... (from `\break`) shows in the output, because *this* exercises the page builder. p. 280-281 say that `\vskip` and `\kern` commands cause items to be appended to the current vertical list, but not that they exercise the page builder. Thus, if you use `\showlists` right after such a command, you see the item in “recent contribs”, not on the “current page”. For your `\penalty 10000`, that must be this part of page 125: “The chosen breakpoint itself is
placed at the very top of the recent contributions. If it is a penalty item, the value of the penalty is recorded in `\outputpenalty` and...

Comment: ... the penalty in the contribution list is changed to `10000` (...)”. To be clear, in the unmodified example: 1) The line `% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#`
refers to the first `\topskip` glue item (first legal breakpoint) but is only printed when TeX digests the `\line{}` (a box digested in vertical mode exercises the page builder, but a `\vskip` command doesn't). 2) The line `% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*` refers to the glue item from `\vfill` (second legal breakpoint) but is only printed when TeX digests the `\penalty-'10000000000` (`\penalty` exercises the page builder, but not `\vfill`).

Comment: So, it turns out that TeXbook p.113 tells lies? "`%` is written whenever a legal breakpoint is being moved from the list of recent contributions to the current page list" (i.e., whenever page builder is exercised). Next, "the `%` lines are generated by the penalty or glue items". From these it follows that penalty or glue items exercise page builder. But you discovered that page builder is exercised by box and penalty.

Comment: I don't see lies here (except maybe “generated for” would be clearer than “generated by”). Each `% ` line corresponds to a legal breakpoint moved from recent contributions to the current page. Glue items (when immediately preceded by a non-discardable item) and penalty items are legal breakpoints, so they can have `% ` lines corresponding to them. But the sentences you quoted **don't say** that a `% ` line is printed *whenever page builder is exercised*. What is said is that *when the page builder is exercised* (cf. p. 280-281), items are moved from recent contributions to the...

Comment: ... current page list, and whenever an item moved this way, effectively put on the current page list (thus not a discarded item as can happen before the first box), is a legal breakpoint, *then* a corresponding `% ` line is printed. So, you could have several `% ` lines printed at once if items such as glue or kerns have been waiting in recent contributions for the page builder to finally put them on the current page list. Each `% ` line is for a legal breakpoint, but it is only printed the next time the page builder is exercised (which is at the same time as the command is digested for a...

Comment: ... `\penalty` item, but differed for glue items and kerns). For instance, take the original example and insert `\line{}\kern-10pt\vskip 20pt\kern30pt\showlists\break` before `\end`. With adequate `\tracing...`, you'll see `{\hbox} (...) % t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#` (the `\hbox` triggered the page builder which printed the `\topskip` first legal breakpoint), then `{vertical mode: \kern} {\vskip} {\kern} {\showlists}` which will show the two kerns and one glue item waiting in “recent contributions”, then `\break` is expanded, TeX digests the `\penalty` from its expansion, which exercices the...

Comment: ... page builder a second time: `% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*`, which shows the infinity-cost breakpoint at the kern item due to `\kern-10pt` (nothing to do with the `10.0` amount in `t=10.0`, which was contributed by `\topskip`) and decides TeX to invoke the `\output` routine.

Comment: If you want to see the `% ` lines for *several* legal breakpoints printed at once after the corresponding items have been waiting for some time in “recent contributions” for the page builder to be exercised, you can start again from the original examlpe and insert `\topskip=0pt\line{}\kern-11pt\vskip 20pt\kern30pt\vskip12pt\showlists\break` before `\end`. After the `\line{}`, the legal breakpoints are the two kerns (because they are immediately followed by glue) and the penalty item from `\break`. The `\showlists` commands shows four items waiting in recent contributions ...

Comment: ... (`\kern -11.0 \glue 20.0 \kern 30.0 \glue 12.0`), then after expanding `\break`, TeX executes (digests: this is shown within braces) `\penalty`, which triggers printing of these two lines: `% t=0.0 g=0.0 b=0 p=0 c=0#`
and `% t=9.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*`, one for each kern. The `t=0.0` for the first kern is because we've used `\topskip=0pt` and the `\line{}` doesn't bring any height or depth. The `t=9.0` for the second kern is because if the page were broken there, the page total would be 0pt (`\topskip`) + 0pt (`\line{}`)  - 11pt (first kern) + 20pt (`\vskip` before the second kern).

Comment: I updated the answer. One subtle point that caught me at first: in the comments, we saw that the printing of `% ` lines for legal breakpoints may be delayed when they are related to items that don't trigger the page builder when the corresponding commands are digested by TeX. This applies to all the test code we inserted before `\end` in the comments, but it **doesn't** apply to the interesting code from the example, because that code is the code implicitly inserted by `\end` (where there is actually no `\line` macro to expand, only an `\hbox` command), and page 283 says that...

Comment: ...  the page builder is exercised after the implicit items have been put on the main vertical list (page 264 was rather evasive on this point). AFAIUI, this implies that the costs associated to glue items are evaluated immediately—not in a delayed fashion as happens when the items come from commands read from the input stream. This doesn't change the outcome, but I had to carefully check and rephrase many parts after realizing this fact. :-/ (in case you read the previous version of this comment, I only removed the word “here” after “This doesn't change the outcome”)

Comment: There is an error in your comment: "due to \kern-10pt" must be "due to `\topskip`". And on the whole, "...at the kern item due to \kern-10pt (nothing to do with the 10.0 amount in t=10.0, which was contributed by \topskip)" should be changed to "at `\kern-10pt` due to `\topskip`".

Comment: No, I really meant what I wrote there. You have `\line{}\kern-10pt\vskip 20pt (...)`. The `\kern-10pt` tokens (6 tokens from the input stream, starting with the `\kern` command) causes a `\kern` item to be appended to the “recent contributions”. This `\kern` item is immediately followed by a glue item, the one produced by the `\vskip 20pt`. When both get moved to the current page, this makes the `\kern` item a legitimate breakpoint. `\topskip` is unrelated to the item itself. The only role it plays here is that it explains the `t=10.0` printed for the `\kern` item (this is the amount...

Comment: ... of material before it on the current page, since `\topskip` is before the `\hbox` which comes before the `\kern` item). In case you forgot: a `\kern` item is a legal breakpoint iff it is immediately followed by glue (TeXbook p. 110). This is the case for the `\kern` item produced by the `\kern-10pt` tokens from the input stream.

Comment: I think this is a simple misunderstanding. Where I wrote “`% t=10.0 g=0.0 b=* p=0 c=*`, which shows the infinity-cost breakpoint at the kern item due to `\kern-10pt`”, the “due to `\kern-10pt`” part refers to the `\kern` item, not to the infinity cost (i.e., I'm just saying that the `\kern` item is due to the `\kern` command obtained from the six tokens`\kern-10pt`, and this item is a legitimate breakpoint with associated cost *c* = ∞). It is true that `\topskip` plays a significant role in the computation that leads to *c* = ∞, but this is simply not what I was saying in that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

It is tex-the-program's final endgame to flush out the insert:

tex.web has

```
@ We don't want to leave |main_control| immediately when a |stop| command
is sensed, because it may be necessary to invoke an \.{\\output} routine
several times before things really grind to a halt. (The output routine
might even say `\.{\\gdef\\end\{...\}}', to prolong the life of the job.)
Therefore |its_all_over| is |true| only when the current page
and contribution list are empty, and when the last output was not a
``dead cycle.''

@<Declare act...@>=
function its_all_over:boolean; {do this when \.{\\end} or \.{\\dump} occurs}
label exit;
begin if privileged then
  begin if (page_head=page_tail)and(head=tail)and(dead_cycles=0) then
    begin its_all_over:=true; return;
    end;
  back_input; {we will try to end again after ejecting residual material}
  tail_append(new_null_box);
  width(tail):=hsize;
  tail_append(new_glue(fill_glue));
  tail_append(new_penalty(-@'10000000000));@/
  build_page; {append \.{\\hbox to \\hsize\{\}\\vfill\\penalty-'10000000000}}
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  end;
its_all_over:=false;
exit:end;
```

Comment: This is mentioned on p.264 of TeXbook. I guess the meaning is that if `\insert` which occupies the whole page is used, there has to be some additional text, so second page is inevitable. Still, I'm not sure I completely understand how the explanation on p.264 applies to OP.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko in your case when it hits `\end` the main vertical list is not empty (there is an `\insert` node left) so the clause on page 262 means the the \line is added and `\end` is called again